# Aligning Radio Buttons Below a DIV

Tags: css

Disclaimer: I am a VB guy with 4 days of jQuery and CSS experience. I am just trying to figure out the web design world!

I want to learn how to approach a design like this:

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgxDz.jpg)

Figuring it out from the image, I believe there's an outer div with an image center aligned and a white border around the image

The image has a left and right button on either sides that overlaps the images (God knows how's that even possible!)

Below the Outer Div are four radio buttons aligned one after the other

How to go about this design?  (interested in just the design, not the coding part)

Comments/explanations would help! Thanks.

Edit: With my 16 hrs of experience, this is what I have so far http://jsfiddle.net/29mH2/2/. Sorry for being such a n00b!

```
<div id="somediv">
    <img src=""/>
    <img src=""/>
    <img src=""/>
</div>
<input type="radio" name="op">
<input type="radio" name="op">
<input type="radio" name="op">
<input type="radio" name="op">

div {
    background-color:blue;
    border: 2px white;
    position: absolute;
}

img {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Right mouse click the browser window and select "View Source...".  Then you can see how it works.

Comment: actually it's just a screenshot I have with me

Comment: This is a very easy design, if this is intimidating you then I HIGHLY recommend learn more about `css` and `html`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @JoshPowell. That's why I am here!

Comment: I think you're looking at something generated with this jQuery plugin: http://wowslider.com/

Comment: No problem and I see the question is more clear, best of luck!

Comment: I would read up on http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html if you want to learn about how CSS works visually.

Comment: @bittenbytailfly yes that looks similar minus the boom-baam happening on that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned you're working with jQuery already, take a look at [this tutorial](http://designmodo.com/responsive-slider/) and [a working example of the result](http://jsfiddle.net/y66Jx/).

Basically, you're going to want to make two list elements. 
One will contain the slides, and the other will contain the navigation buttons.

---

EDIT:

Since you're just looking for an example of the design, [Here's a basic example](http://jsfiddle.net/GeCt9/7/) that shows how to make a layout like you're talking about without any actual functionality.

HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
    <img class="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/dL3io.jpg" />

    <div class="navigation-arrows">
      <div class="arrow left"><</div>
      <div class="arrow right">></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="navigation">
  <input type="radio" name="op">
  <input type="radio" name="op">
  <input type="radio" name="op">
  <input type="radio" name="op">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}

.slider,
.slider .image {
    width: 400px;
}

.slider .image,
.navigation-arrows,
.navigation-arrows .arrow {
    position: absolute;
}

.navigation-arrows,
.navigation-arrows .arrow {
    height: 25px;
}

.slider {
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

.slider .image {
    height: 250px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.navigation-arrows {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 125px;
}

.navigation-arrows .arrow {
    border-radius: 12.5px;
    background: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.navigation-arrows .left {
    left: 5px;
}

.navigation-arrows .right {
    right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: As I said, I am not interested in the coding part. I just want to see how this kind of design can be achieved with CSS. I need the radio buttons

Comment: I just updated my answer with a solution that uses radio buttons.

Comment: thanks for being such a help but honestly I just want the design (no functionality). Try to visualize from a Beginners's perspective. I am interested to see what bare-bones CSS does it take to just design the div, an image, some radio buttons and those overlapping left and right arrows. Can you edit your example to remove the coding part please.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also show if CSS is capable of achieving those left right arrows 'over' the image. Is that even possible?

Comment: Yeah, that's easy to do. Updated my answer.

Comment: that's awesome! Css is awesome! Just one question. Is there a way to automatically calculate and center the left/right arrows with respect to the image, if the image size changes. Currently I see that I will have to do it manually

Comment: Yeah, definitely. You just have to make a few tweaks to the CSS (set the width of the arrow container to 100%) and nest it inside the image wrapper. I just updated it again so you can see how its done (try changing the width of the image on line #7 of the CSS). http://jsfiddle.net/GeCt9/6/

Comment: Cody thanks for your time and help! This is what I wanted to learn!